# cURL isn't working, returning an error

Tags: curl

I'm trying to pass get variables through a url to generate xml data, pass the variables and grab the xml data with curl and bring it back to the webpage so I can parse the data and use one of the elements attribute values and put it into a php variable to display on the page.

So it seems like I've been at this forever but I have the following code, (fyi. I put 'password' in place of the real password. 'shipper number in here' in place of real shipper number and 'token here' in place of real token for this thread)

```
$xml = '
weight_system="IMPERIAL" shipper_number="shipper number in here" destination_postal_code="'.$data5['zip'].'" service_type="1"
';

$xml2 = '
total_pieces="'.$value.'" total_weight="'.$weight.'"
';       

$token = 'token here'; 
$base_url = 'https://www.shippingco.com/XML/RatingXML.jsp'; 

$request_url = $base_url . '?' . http_build_query(array(
'shipment' => '<shipment ' . $xml . '><total ' . $xml2 . '/></shipment>',
'token' => $token
));

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  '../cert/ca.crt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '../cert/mycert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '../cert/mykey.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'password');
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Which produces:

```
error: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

I've tried to call the paths using getcwd().'../cert/...', getcwd().'/cert/...', 'public_html/cert/...' and checking to see if the path works by using this code,

```
if (file_exists('../cert/ca.crt')) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

and file_exists returns yes when calling ../cert/ca.crt so I'm using that path in the curl code. But I'm still not sure what else is going wrong.

I purchased an SSL and dedicated IP address encase you're wondering. I have the RSA key, SSL cert, CA bundle and a password and I saved them as the file names and formats listed above in their own directory called cert. If I saved them as the wrong file format or with the wrong extension, please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Directory Structure:

```
public_html (root)
cert (dir inside public_html)
ca.crt (file inside cert)
mycert.pem (file inside cert)
mykey.pem (file inside cert)
secure (dir inside public_html)
shopping.php (file inside secure)
```

Comment: Can you add explicit checks for both the certificate and the key file?  I'm always suspicious seeing relative paths that code is not always running where you think it's running.  FWIW, there isn't any different between `../foo` and `getcwd() . '../foo` (unless you cache the result and `chdir()` before using it).

Comment: Do you mean run file_exists for ca.crt, mycert.pem and mykey.pem? Ok I  just did that and they exist with paths ../cert/ca.crt, ../cert/mycert.pem and ../cert/mykey.pem. Error still exists. As for using getcwd() and not using it in the file_exists test shows that not using it returns 'yes' and using it returns 'no' and then not using it again returns 'yes'. so no cache issue there.

Comment: I just added the directory structure to my op to show why I use the path with the 2 dots in front. I tried putting the directory 'cert' inside the 'secure' directory and changing the paths to suit, pretty much taking out the ../ that starts the paths and still get the same error as stated in my op. So I just put 'cert' back under public_html and went back to the way I was calling the paths before since that didn't solve anything.

Comment: Anyone have any idea on what's going wrong here?...

Comment: If more code or information is needed I can post more to this thread. Would really appreciate some help from someone who's done this kind of thing before. If curl can't accomplish what I'm trying to do, is there a better method? Thanks.

Comment: Anybody know whats going on there? Larsks?